# In Typescript: How to extract separate input and output types for a function?

Tags: typescript

For this function:

```
function first(x: number, y: string) {
return {
    a: x,
    b: y
  };
}

function second(z: typeof first()) {
  return {
    c: 6,
    ...z
  }
}
```

`typeof first()` is, ofcourse, invalid,

I'd like to use the inferred output type of `first` in `second`'s signature.
Is it possible (I'm assuming no but hope to be surprised)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at this moment it is not possible to extract the return type of a function.

There is a thread on github where this is discussed though. You can see it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606).

What you can do right now is to define a specific type to be used in as the return type of the first function and the type of the parameters received by the first function. It's also a lot more explicit and easier to understand.

```js
interface ReturnType {
    a: number,
    b: string
}
function first(x: number, y: string): ReturnType {
    return {
        a: x,
        b: y
    };
}

function second(z: ReturnType) {
    return {
        c: 6,
        ...z
    }
}
```